# Laravel 8: sending request data between classes

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time sending input data between classes.

I have a class with a method that recieves a text input fields data that works normally:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\estate_agent_related\validation\branch_checkVal;


class postCode_input extends Controller
{
    public function retrieve(branch_checkVal $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $user_input_postcode = $request->input('brach_postcode');
        $postcode = str_replace(' ', '', $user_input_postcode);
        return $postcode;
    }
}
```

I have another class that has a method that extends the class above, howver, i can't figure out how to send the input data to the class method above via the class below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related\postCode_input;

class postCode_check extends postCode_input 
{
    public function check(postCode_input $postCode_input)
    {
        $postCode_input = new postCode_input;
        return $postCode_input->retrieve();
        // return Estate_agent::where('postcode', $postCode_input)->exists();
    }
}
```

I hope i've explained this well enough. If not, Please let me know and i'll provide more info.

Thanks

Comment: i dont understand the passing a controller to a controller method part

Comment: hi @lagbox, Basically I want to have a class/method to check my postcode input and then return it. I then want to then use the return data elsewhere - like in another class. Does that make more sense? (I'm new to laravel / mvc & oop)

Comment: where does `check` come into play? is there a route action pointing at that method?

Comment: Thanks for your help @lagbox, i've just managed to figure out the issue (answer provided). The parameters in the check method needed to be the same as the receive method

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to get the result of retrieve function in your check function, Since you've extended the base class then retreive method can be called on the same instance of the extended class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related\postCode_input;

class postCode_check extends postCode_input 
{
    public function check(postCode_input $postCode_input)
    {
        // you don't need to intitalize your primary class
        // $postCode_input = new postCode_input();

        // you can call the retrieve function on $this instance 
        return $this->retrieve($postCode_input);
        // return Estate_agent::where('postcode', $postCode_input)->exists();
    }
}
```

Another way could be to type-hint the request instance on the check method

```
 public function check(postCode_input $postCode_input, Request $request)
    {
         //Access the data like this 
         $request->input('name');
    }
```

Comment: Thank for replying so quickly Ashu. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I get an error:    ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related\postCode_input::retrieve(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ra_dev/app/Http/Controllers/postCode_related/postCode_check.php on line 14 and exactly 1 expected
http://localhost/branchcheck/postcodecheck

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ashu , i've just managed to figure out the issue (answer provided). The parameters in the check method needed to be the same as the receive method

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your help. I've figured out the issue.

The problem is the check method required the same parameters as the retrive method.

see below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\estate_agent_related\validation\branch_checkVal;


class postCode_input extends Controller
{
    public function retrieve(branch_checkVal $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $user_input_postcode = $request->input('brach_postcode');
        $postcode = str_replace(' ', '', $user_input_postcode);
        return $postcode;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related\postCode_input;

class postCode_check extends postCode_input 
{
    public function check(branch_checkVal $request)
    {
        return $this->retrieve($request);
    }
}
```

I arrived here after recieving the error below:

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\postCode_related\postCode_input::retrieve() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\estate_agent_related\validation\branch_checkVal, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ra_dev/app/Http/Controllers/postCode_related/postCode_check.php on line 15
```